# IntelliJ Shortcut for code outline

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij and migrating over from Eclipse. I have a question about a keyboard shortcut to show the outline of a java source file. In Eclipse we do Ctrl+O which basically shows the outline of the class. However I'm not able to figure out the shortcut to do the same in Intellij.

Based on Intellij documentation it says we need to press Cmd+F12(I moved to Mac as well) but that never invokes the code outline. Kindly help.

Comment: Ctrl + F12 in windows.

Comment: In Intellij if you choose Eclipse keymap in Settings>Keymap, Ctrl+O works.

Comment: This worked for me. Changed the settings to use Eclipse keymap. Thanks

Comment: @Sid..If you provide response in the form of an answer I can mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to open [**File Structure**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html) popup and show code outline.

Here is a list of very often used keys of Eclipse and IntelliJ.

See also: [IntelliJ's Reference Card for Keymaps on Mac and Linux/Windows](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).

[image]

Comment: ctrl+F12 or Cmd+F12 never works for me

Comment: @AnirudhKubatoor, what does it do for that combination?

Comment: It just shows the volume sign appear and then disappear.

Comment: @AnirudhKubatoor: ok. if possible, report it to idea team https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: What I figured out is for OSX 10.5 onwards Fn+Cmd+F12 works to get the outline/file structure.